# Delete duplicates in a list compiled of different lists and also delete

Tags: list-manipulation

I've got three lists: Lst1 has 100 different values for "r". Lst2 has 100 different values for "a". And `Lst3=Pi*Lst1^2*Lst2`. In Lst3 I've got duplicates and I want to get rid of them, but I also want to get rid of the corresponding values for "r" and "a" in Lst1 and Lst2.

I'm using this now because the values are quite precise.

```
DeleteDuplicatesBy[Lst3, Round[#, 10^-12] &]
```

This gives me the correct Lst3, but I also need to know and get rid of the corresponding values in Lst1 and Lst2.

So basically I want to get three lists as an output: Lst3 without duplicates, Lst1 and Lst2 without the values which computed the duplicate in Lst3. My apologies if this kind of question has been asked before, I'm quite new to Mathematica.

Comment: Combine the lists (see `Transpose`) and use `DeleteDuplicatesBy`.

Comment: `{Lst1,Lst2}=Part[Gather[Transpose[{Lst1,Lst2}],#1[[1]]==#2[[1]]&&#1[[2]]==#2[[2]]&],All,1]//Transpose` should in principle return `Lst1` and`Lst2` without duplicate entries. Then you can produce `Lst3` and hopefully, there will be no duplicates...

Comment: `DeleteDuplicatesBy[Transpose[{Lst1, Lst2, Lst3}], Last]`, and transpose again if you want to.

Comment: @Szabolcs, forgot to thank you at the time. Thank you very much for your input, it worked like magic!